# jQuery change divs html with pauses

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/javascript-sleep)
>   [How to delay execution in between the following in my javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990725/how-to-delay-execution-in-between-the-following-in-my-javascript)

Hi i want to change html of two divs. But have pause between it

```
$(#div1).html('Div1 content');
$(#div2).html('Div2 content');
//wait 5 seconds
$(#div1).html('Div1 new content');
//wait 5 seconds
$(#div2).html('Div2 new content');
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript sleep](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/javascript-sleep) and (closer related) [How to delay execution in between the following in my javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990725/how-to-delay-execution-in-between-the-following-in-my-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick way to do it would be to chain a couple [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout)s.

```
$('#div1').html('Div1 content');
$('#div2').html('Div2 content');

setTimeout(function () {
    $('#div1').html('Div1 new content');

    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#div2').html('Div2 new content');
    }, 5000);

}, 5000);
```

<sub>Don't forget to quote your `$()` selectors, too.</sub>

Comment: Thank you. I've used setTimeout before, but not in the right way :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `setTimeOut()` function

Comment: It's actually `setTimeout(function () {}, delay)`

Comment: And you actually want `setInterval` most likely.

Comment: Yes sorry it's setTimeout, but no I don't want setInterval. He wants a delay, not a loop

Comment: @ElliotBonneville `setInterval` will make it happen periodically. I think @gv0zd wants it to happen just once

Comment: Yes, but he'd store the setInterval then clear it after X loops. `setTimeout` works too, I suppose.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville: Why do you think anyone wants to loop?

Comment: why does everybody write anything to confuse all others?

Comment: @FelixKling it's a pretty concise way of calling a function a few times such that he won't have to chain 5 `setTimeout`s.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville: Who is talking about five `setTimeout`s? Sure, you can use `setInterval` if you want to do the *same thing* periodically, but that is not the case here at all. OP has two different statements he wants to delay...

Comment: Looks like what @RobHruska was doing, which could lead a beginner to writing that out five times instead of using a recursive function or something. Edit: Yes, I see that now. My bad. It's not a very extendable pattern, though...

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#div1').html('Div1 content');
$('#div2').html('Div2 content');

//wait 5 seconds   
$('#div1').delay(5000)
    .queue(function(n) {
        $(this).html("Div1 new content");       
    });

//wait another 5 seconds
$('#div2').delay(10000)
    .queue(function(n) {
        $(this).html("Div2 new content");       
    });
});
```