# JS - location reload with delay after function executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am running a JS / AJAX script to update data in my table and once the script is done, I would like to reload the page. However, with my current code, it reloads immediately, is there any way to delay the reload for 3 secs?

```
// close modal and refresh page
$('#EditRecordModal').modal('hide');
location.reload();
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delay execution in between the following in my javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990725/how-to-delay-execution-in-between-the-following-in-my-javascript)

Comment: Do you get a response from your database/server? You can wait until the response comes and then reload the page/display error message if not updated in database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#EditRecordModal').modal('hide');
setTimeout(function(){location.reload()}, 3000);
```